# Weird attribute with guid 1082E6C2-7660-4945-8E78-228A3B3329F6 required for MFCreateAudioRenderer

Tags: winapi, audio, visual-c++, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to create an instance of an audio renderer with a given GUID by calling `MFCreateAudioRenderer` with the attributes pointer set. I've set all the required values, but the call returns `E_INVALIDARG` and `mftrace.exe` shows

```
13808,33E0 15:09:52.27643 CMFAttributesDetours::GetUnknown @014C4550 - enter
13808,33E0 15:09:52.27644 CMFAttributesDetours::GetUnknown @014C4550 attribute not found guidKey = {1082E6C2-7660-4945-8E78-228A3B3329F6}
13808,33E0 15:09:52.27644 CMFAttributesDetours::GetUnknown @014C4550 - exit (failed hr=0xC00D36E6 MF_E_ATTRIBUTENOTFOUND)
```

I can't find this GUID anywhere and don't know what to set. Any advices?

Minimal sample to reproduce:

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>

#include <Mfidl.h>
#include <Mfapi.h>
#include <Mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <Functiondiscoverykeys_devpkey.h>
#include <Audioclient.h>
#include <Codecapi.h>
#include <Audiopolicy.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Mfplat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Mf.lib")

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    CComPtr<IMMDeviceEnumerator> pMMDeviceEnumerator;
    pMMDeviceEnumerator.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator));
    std::map<std::wstring, CComPtr<IMMDevice>> Devices;
    if (pMMDeviceEnumerator)
    {
        CComPtr<IMMDeviceCollection> pMMDeviceCollection;
        if (SUCCEEDED(pMMDeviceEnumerator->EnumAudioEndpoints(EDataFlow::eRender, DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE, &pMMDeviceCollection)))
        {
            UINT nDeviceCount = 0;
            if (SUCCEEDED(pMMDeviceCollection->GetCount(&nDeviceCount)))
            {
                UINT nDeviceIndex = 0;
                while (nDeviceIndex < nDeviceCount)
                {
                    CComPtr<IMMDevice> pMMDevice;
                    if (SUCCEEDED(pMMDeviceCollection->Item(nDeviceIndex, &pMMDevice)))
                    {
                        CComPtr<IPropertyStore> pPropertyStore;
                        if (SUCCEEDED(pMMDevice->OpenPropertyStore(STGM_READ, &pPropertyStore)))
                        {
                            PROPVARIANT Variant;
                            PropVariantInit(&Variant);
                            if (SUCCEEDED(pPropertyStore->GetValue(PKEY_Device_FriendlyName, &Variant)))
                            {
                                wchar_t* pId = nullptr;
                                if (SUCCEEDED(pMMDevice->GetId(&pId)))
                                {
                                    Devices.emplace(pId, pMMDevice);
                                    CoTaskMemFree(pId);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ++nDeviceIndex;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    std::vector<CComPtr<IMFMediaSink>> MediaSinks;
    for (const auto& Device : Devices)
    {
        CComPtr<IMFAttributes> pAttributes;
        MFCreateAttributes(&pAttributes, 0);
        CComPtr<IMFMediaSink> pAudioRenderer;
        HRESULT hResult = pAttributes->SetString(MF_AUDIO_RENDERER_ATTRIBUTE_ENDPOINT_ID, Device.first.c_str());
        hResult = pAttributes->SetUINT32(MF_AUDIO_RENDERER_ATTRIBUTE_ENDPOINT_ROLE, ERole::eMultimedia);
        hResult = pAttributes->SetUINT32(MF_AUDIO_RENDERER_ATTRIBUTE_STREAM_CATEGORY, AUDIO_STREAM_CATEGORY::AudioCategory_BackgroundCapableMedia);
        hResult = pAttributes->SetUINT32(MF_AUDIO_RENDERER_ATTRIBUTE_FLAGS, 0);
        hResult = pAttributes->SetGUID(MF_AUDIO_RENDERER_ATTRIBUTE_SESSION_ID, GUID_NULL);
        hResult = MFCreateAudioRenderer(pAttributes, &pAudioRenderer);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hResult))
        {
            MediaSinks.push_back(pAudioRenderer);
        }
    }
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

Comment: @dan [You still haven't stopped…?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850854/how-to-intercept-alt1-or-altnumber-key-pressed-event-c#comment74738138_43850854) The extra tags on this one are fine, but a language tag is *not* wrong.

Comment: It might so happen that you don't need this unknown attribute. The problem in first place is that your other attributes are not good. I'd start with commenting out the line with stream category (where the used value is deprecated).

Comment: @RomanR. if that one is commented out mftrace properly complains about it.

Comment: @RomanR. MF_AUDIO_RENDERER_ATTRIBUTE_FLAGS and MF_AUDIO_RENDERER_ATTRIBUTE_SESSION_ID trigger a nice appropriate warning in mftrace. I tried other values for the role and stream category but with no luck:(

Comment: @RomanR. ok, thanks, now this was helpful :)

Comment: @CodyGray: Not even the extra tags are fine. There is no MFC code anywhere, in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related [MSDN bit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369729) is:

> ...If you specify a device role, the SAR uses whatever audio device has been assigned for that role. To specify the device role, set the `MF_AUDIO_RENDERER_ATTRIBUTE_ENDPOINT_ROLE` attribute.

You identify the device by either ID or ROLE, the two are mutually exclusive, hence `E_INVALIDARG` when you provide both at a time.